# Why are lifetimes a problem only when you take a reference to a mutable reference?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the following Rust code, which compiles fine:

```rust
struct T {
    x: String,
}

fn ret_x<'a, 'b>(c: &'a mut &'b T) -> &'b str {
    return &c.x;
}
```

However, if I have:

```rust
struct T {
    x: String,
}

fn ret_x<'a, 'b>(c: &'a mut &'b mut T) -> &'b str {
    return &c.x;
}
```

Then it gives me an error about lifetimes:

```
function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'b` but it is returning data with lifetime `'a`
```

What's the difference between these two cases?

Is this somehow due to reborrowing? When the "inner" reference is immutable, Rust can just copy the reference without borrowing from c itself, whereas for the case where the "inner" reference is mutable, it needs to borrow from c?

Comment: Read about [subtyping and variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html). It should explain you a couple of things.

Comment: This does not explain **why**, but you can add `where 'a: 'b` in order to restrict the usage to the situation where `'a` lasts at least as long as `'b`.

Comment: Why would you want to assign different lifetimes to a reference and a reference to that reference? This just seems like a strange corner case for language testing.